# MapBox Randomizing Building Color

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

Is it possible to loop through all of the buildings on the map an assign them different colours, or a different property value that drives a thematic grouping?

I have code to loop through the buildings:

```
features = map.queryRenderedFeatures({ layers: ["building"], filter: ['==', 'extrude', 'true']});
features.forEach(function(feature){
  // how to change feature colour or property in here?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of ways achieving something like what you want.

#### Feature state

If your buildings layer has feature IDs, you can use `setFeatureState` to set a state on each building.

```js
features = map.querySourceFeatures('building', { sourceLayer: 'buildings' }));
features.forEach(function(feature){
  if (!map.getFeatureState({ id: feature.id, source: 'building', sourceLayer: 'buildings' }).color) {
    map.setFeatureState({ id: feature.id, source: 'building', sourceLayer: 'buildings' }, { color: makeRandomColor() }
  }
});
```

You can then use `['feature-state', 'color']` in an expression.

#### Quasi random

If there's no feature ID, you might be able to use some other attribute in a way that appears to be random. For instance, if there's some other kind of ID, you can use a mod function to map it to a color, in a way that might look kind of random.